# Ranking data sets based on means, standard deviations, etc

Tags: anova

My goal is to take several data sets with varying sample sizes and variances and to somehow rank them by their tendency to be larger or which data set is most likely to end up with a higher mean after being extrapolated. I am not very skilled in statistics, could anyone help me out?